# Tools to perform load tests on my web

Tags: tomcat, servlets, web-applications, https, embedded-jetty

I have a webapp embedded in Tomcat. I would like to perform load tests to simulate high number of users sending parallel request.
I can easily generate HTTP requests that should be sent by these "virtual users", it's not a problem.

I'm just looking for a tool that could send these HTTPS requests automatically based on a configurable traffic pattern (number of users, busy hours, ...). This tool should also perform statistics on the request duration.

Any suggestions?
Thanks,

Sébastien.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple HTTP or HTTPS requests there are a whole bunch of free/open source and commerical tools out there with varying capabilities and cost:

Open Source:

- Apache JMeter
- Gattling
- Grinder

Commercial:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Team Suite
- Loadrunner
- Rational Performance Tester

All of these tools can generate HTTP traffic in volumes, have powerful libraries for dynamically capturing values, doing asserts on responses and graphing and doing cumulative reports on response statistics.

Comment: I will start with the Open Source and Apache JMeter as it seems quite powerful
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[apache jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) is a good load testing tool for web applications.